# Slice keeps repopulating old entries in loop

Tags: go

I'm seeing a weird phenomenon while looping over a queue implemented on a slice, and I've never experienced it before:

```
fmt.Printf("BEFORE LOOP\n")

for len(queue) > 0 {
    fmt.Printf("BEFORE-QUEUE=(%d) %v\n", len(queue), queue)
    currentPath, queue := queue[0], queue[1:]
    fmt.Printf("PATH=[%s] AFTER-QUEUE=(%d) %v\n", currentPath, len(queue), queue)
}

fmt.Printf("AFTER LOOP\n")
```

Output:

```
BEFORE LOOP
BEFORE-QUEUE=(1) [../../test/asset]
PATH=[../../test/asset] AFTER-QUEUE=(0) []
BEFORE-QUEUE=(1) [../../test/asset]
PATH=[../../test/asset] AFTER-QUEUE=(0) []
BEFORE-QUEUE=(1) [../../test/asset]
PATH=[../../test/asset] AFTER-QUEUE=(0) []
BEFORE-QUEUE=(1) [../../test/asset]
PATH=[../../test/asset] AFTER-QUEUE=(0) []
BEFORE-QUEUE=(1) [../../test/asset]
...
```

This is running via "go run" under version 1.11.4 . I'm not sure what in my situation/design has triggered this behavior.

Thoughts/Analyses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what's happening is that we're using short-variable assignment (the new-assignment operator ":=") to assign the new variable and update the queue (combined into a multiple-assignment, out of convenience). This is creating a **new** instance of *queue* within the block, whose scope takes precedence over the one assigned in the outer block. So, within the current iteration of the loop body, we have a temporary instance of *queue* that may be empty, but is then discarded at the end of the iteration. To solve this issue for the current use-case, predefine *currentPath* and then switch to using "=" rather than ":=":

```
for len(queue) > 0 {
    var currentPath string
    currentPath, queue = queue[0], queue[1:]
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Sorry about that. I finally saw the answer just after posting, and rushed to write a response before somebody else wasted their time. Still, thanks for responding.

Comment: <- "finally saw the answer" in that it occurred to me almost immediately after I posted.

Comment: I didn't waste any time as I saw it right away - only because I did exactly the same thing recently.

Answer (score 2):

You are "shadowing" queue - ie. creating a new queue variable (due to :=). Try:

```
currentPath := queue[0]
queue = queue[1:]
```